# Using catalina_opts for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to understand the parameters in catalina_opts.
Can someone explain to me whats the use of "-D" parameter and -server here-

for eg calina_opts= -server -Dhostname=...

Answer (score 2):

**-server** instructs the launcher to use the Java HotSpot Server VM instead of client VM.The Java JVM can optimize a number of things for server environments.

**-D** is used to set java [system properties](http://%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/misc-system/environment-variables.shtml)